# How can I enable an external library in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I am hoping to get autocompletion within PhpStorm. 
The source of of the library  is installed *globally* in my home dir `/home/user/npm/lib/node_modules` and not available locally in My project directory.

How can I enable code assistance (autocompletion etc) in for this external library in phpstorm?

Answer (score 2):

Enable `Node.js` item in `File | Settings | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`.

Also following tips will be helpful for you:

- [WebStorm - Node.js Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMiU8zACVgA&list=PLQ176FUIyIUYnLuYVKM6JhVd6ukPgzdW7&index=9) *screencast with using WebStrom but everything work same on PhpStrom*
- [PhpStorm Help - Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/node-js.html)

Comment: thanks,  yes the library  for `node` itself has been loaded, what I have been trying to enable is code completion/assistance for 3rd party libraries. It seems PhpStorm will try to index and provides code assistance automatically for new libaries - but when it fails how can check this?

Comment: @user4668401 You need enable `TypeScript Community Stubs` how to do that check this **[video](https://youtu.be/9izXNWHD5Qg?t=174)** also this case mention **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20046695/2650174)**

Comment: @user4668401 Man give me to know if my answer is helpful for you. *If not I just delete it*

Comment: thanks. I just your answer upvote now. I ended up solving the problem using vim and ctags. It seemed easier. your answer probably works it just seemed like I needed to do a lot of research on the links you gave - to find out if it worked or not!

Comment: @user4668401 ok. But finally I suggest you to end up on PhpStorm because this very handy tool